# Netbeans Turn off glassfish logging (tyrus/grizzly)

Tags: java, logging, netbeans, glassfish

How do I turn off the logging in my Console output? I don't want to see the output of my Java program:

```
Nov 01, 2013 12:01:29 PM org.glassfish.tyrus.server.ServerContainerFactory create
INFO: Provider class loaded: org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.GrizzlyEngine
Nov 01, 2013 12:01:29 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
INFO: Started listener bound to [0.0.0.0:8029]
Nov 01, 2013 12:01:29 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
INFO: [HttpServer] Started.
Nov 01, 2013 12:01:29 PM org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server start
INFO: WebSocket Registered apps: URLs all start with ws://localhost:8029
Nov 01, 2013 12:01:29 PM org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server start
INFO: WebSocket server started.
```

Comment: Are you using log4j?  If so, you can just set the logging level to fatal.

Comment: If you do not want to display anything in the Console, just create an application without a Console. Is this possible for your use-case? If not, please tell us more :)

Comment: no wont work if i wanna execute it on an ubuntu-server :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I am surprised that Java does not have this functionality baked in (or that I couldn't find it which is kind of the same thing nowadays)...*

Assign the `System.out` and `System.err` to a stream that does not write anything (to log). In .NET there is the the [Stream.Null](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.null) which is a stream with no backing store, i.e. a *null* stream or a *void* stream.

In Java, such a `Stream` is easily built by extending the `java.io.OutputStream`:

```
class VoidStream extends OutputStream {
    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        // 
        // --------------
        // | void space |
        // --------------
        // 
    }       
}
```

Now, set the `VoidStream` to the `System.out` and `System.err` using `System.setOut()` and `System.Err()` resulting in an empty console,

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new VoidStream());
System.setOut(ps);
System.setErr(ps);
```

In theory, one caveat is `System.console()`, becuase its output stream cannot be set but functions as `printf()` and `format()` can be called. Fortunately, the `System.console()` is only available when the program is run in a terminal ([otherwise it returns null](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.nl/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html)) and who is still working with a terminal? ;-)